# Android - YouTubePlayer API get real position

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

How to get real position of [youtube player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) , the method `getCurrentTimeMillis()` always   returns the same value in ~ 1 sec interval. For example(pseduo):

```
while(true){
 println(youtubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
}
```

the output will be as follows :

```
0
0
0
0
800
800
800
...
1701
1701
....
```

How do I get real position of video ? I want to synchronize my audio and video but I can't figure out how ?